# Jsf - dataTable data doesn't refresh on the client side

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, icefaces

I have an `ice:dataTable` like this.

```
    <ice:dataTable id="pdet"
    value="#{outerBean.nestedClassList}"
    var="nestedObject" rendered="true">

        <ice:column>
             <f:facet name="header">Order Number</f:facet>
             <ice:outputText value="#{nestedObject.orderNumber}" />
        </ice:column>

        <ice:column>
             <f:facet name="header">Qty</f:facet>
             <ice:inputText value="#{nestedObject.qty}" 
                     id="qty" 
                     label="'Qty' FOR 'Order Number':#{nestedObject.orderNumber} "
                     partialSubmit="true" 
                     valueChangeListener="#{nestedObject.qtyChanged}"
                     validator="#{nestedObject.validateQty}">
              </ice:inputText>
         </ice:column>
     </ice:dataTable>
```

There is a drop down list, depend on the selected value, I want to populate the particular data set. Always there is a value for `qty` and that should be allowed to change the value. For an instance, without changing that `qty` `ice:inputText`, if I change the selected value from the drop down list, a new data set will populate, but from the client side, it shows the previous values for the `qty`. But bean keeps the real value. If I use a `ice:outputText`  for the `qty` field, then it shows the exact value. How do I prevent this? What I'm missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Can something (an attribute or validator) be breaking your input? Why don't you try with the simplest `<ice:inputText />` and try to isolate your problem?

Comment: Sorry , I don't understand what you meant by that

Comment: Do you have problems if you use only this `<ice:inputText value="#{nestedObject.qty}" />`?

Comment: Yes. And I need a `ice:inputText` somehow.